# Help in choosing elective subject

Tags: java, image-processing

I am a student of B.Tech CSE and have an option to choose any one of the subjects in the next semester. Below are the options:

1. Enterprise Java
2. Digital Image Processing
3. Compiler Design

I want to settle with something which can be useful to learn while at the same time not put so much burden as to mess up my results.

I know this forum contains excellent teachers in the academic field which will guide me and choose the best possible option for me.

Comment: And Welcome to your community, hope you can ask (and answer) many questions in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I am a student.I was also writing this somewhere else and probably got confused while typing my question.Thanks for bearing!

Comment: Have you already studied Java, or is that entirely new? Say a bit more about your background.

Comment: Which class seems most interesting to you? Take that one.

Comment: I am comfortable and have interest in all the three subjects.And yes, I have some experience in java.

Comment: Oh man, that's like asking, *"Should I have cake, cookies, or chocolates? Which will be the yummiest?"*  You just can't lose.  If you really have no preference between the subjects, look up the teachers and see who has a reputation for running enjoyable courses.

Comment: Fine, I will take Enterprise java to be on the safe side but will study Compiler Design online to apply for higher studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your goals:

If you want to just "get by", take the easiest one. That is probably the one you already know the most about already. Safe. Boring.

If you want to "become as smart as possible", take the hardest one. Unsafe. Live on the edge.

If you want to just get employed in the future, take the most practical one. Hmmm. Looks good on the resume.

If  you yearn for (yet) higher education, take the most theoretical one. The admissions committee will love it.

If they all seem about the same, roll a die.

If you want to get lost in the crowd, take the most popular one. No one will notice me.

If you want some individual attention and a relationship with the faculty, take the least popular one. The prof will be able to help me understand things.

---

You could ask advice from one or more of the instructors, explaining to them your long term goals and seeing how the course contributes to it.

Any of these three courses could be hard or easy, theoretical or not, depending on the teacher and institution, so I won't make more specific suggestions.

---

Whichever you choose, work hard, think deep, live long, prosper.

---

If anyone thinks this is snarky or intended to be humorous, I'd suggest you reconsider. At many points in my life I specifically chose the harder path and have never regretted it. At other times I just went along with the flow and was sorry. But choosing according to my goals turned out to be pretty optimal.